# Is there a tool in Kali Linux that get Wi-Fi passwords only by capturing the traffic?

Tags: wifi

Tools in Kali Linux generally crack Wi-Fi password by injecting packets. Is there a tool that can crack or get the password only by capturing the traffic?

Answer (score 4):

I would say that most of the wifi cracking tools can do their job with or without injection, depending on the commands and parameters you provide.

For example if you are cracking WPA/WPA2, you can "crack" it without injection by waiting for a client to authenticate and by capturing the 4-way handshake, which you then brute force. In that case, you are not using packet injection.

But if you don't want to wait for a client to authenticate, you could deauthenticate one that is already on the network and force it to reauthenticate, but in order to do this, the tool you are using must use packet injection.

The same counts for WEP. If there is enough traffic on the network, you can just wait and collect network traffic. When you collect enough traffic, it will be used by the cracking algorithm to get the password. In that case you do not need injection. But if there is not much traffic, you can speed up the process by injecting some bogus packets into the network.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [airmong-ng](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airmon-ng) that comes installed by default in Kali Linux.

I once used [this](https://github.com/rs91092/fake-ap-rouge-ap-in-wireless-networks) opensource library on Backtrack 5 (ancestor of Kali Linux) that uses [sslstrip](http://www.thoughtcrime.org/software/sslstrip/) created by [Moxie Marlinspike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moxie_Marlinspike) and which  unencrypted HTTP sessions look as much as possible like HTTPS session (to get passwords for Yahoo, Facebook ...) in plain text.  This library relies also on `airmon-ng` to function.

Answer (score 0):

Packet injection is mainly a way to save (a lot of) time by somehow forcing legitimate devices (the access point and connected clients) to produce some specific packets (authentication handshakes, ARP requests, ...) which will help you to crack the access.

These same packets would also occur under normal circumstance, but with at a far lower speed. Therefore, depending on the number of connected Wifi devices the time needed to collect enough data may rise from a few minutes (when you do an *active attack* by actively injecting some forged or replayed packets) to several hours/days/weeks (when you do a *passive attack* by passively collecting legitimate packets).